# How to provide visual feedback when user is tapping ImageView?

Tags: android, user-interface

I have a view in the UI that is technically an extended ImageView inside a RelativeLayout that I'd rather not change, if possible. I want to show a Drawable from resources (a small PNG with a gradient or a frame) at specific coordinates as a visual feedback when user is tapping the screen (there even is a onShowPress callback). What is the simplest way to do this? I don't want to modify the layout.xml from which UI is inflated, and I'm not too enthusiastic about overriding onDraw to do extra job there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one easy way to do it using view animation class:

```
final ImageView aboutButton =   (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.AboutButton);
aboutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Animation myAnim2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(LaunchActivity.this, R.anim.buttons);              
    aboutButton.startAnimation(myAnim2);
    myAnim2.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

        //do on click after animation ends
        Intent intent = new Intent(LaunchActivity.this, MyDialog.class);
        startActivity(intent);  
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        //change the backround of the button etc on click etc...                            
        }
    });                                     
}});
```

Comment: Doesn't suit ImageView well since I can't change background or something. But thanks for the idea.

Comment: After reading your question carefully again, I think that the easiest way is to draw it in your custom view as it already has everything setup for it. Otherwise you could add an image view on top of your custom using its left and top margin within the RelativeLayout, but have to watch for different screen sizes...

Comment: I think you're right, that's the easiest way. I've extended my onDraw method to draw an image on the same canvas over the original image.